# Does it matter that sc.include elements display in the admin showconfig page?

Tags: configuration

We're currently in the process of upgrading to Sitecore 8.2 Update-3, and as part of this are finally moving customizations out of the Sitecore.config into patch files.

One of our needs is to define a new `database` element for a production/content delivery database on our authoring server.

This means that we have a patch file that looks like this on the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <databases>
            <!-- Edit will need to be able to point to both the edit and production databases. -->
            <database id="prodweb" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" patch:after="database[@id='web']">
                <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                <icon>Network/16x16/earth.png</icon>
                <securityEnabled>true</securityEnabled>
                <dataProviders hint="list:AddDataProvider">
                    <dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">
                        <disableGroup>publishing</disableGroup>
                        <prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
                            <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config"/>
                            <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Webdb.config"/>
                        </prefetch>
                    </dataProvider>
                </dataProviders>
                <proxiesEnabled>false</proxiesEnabled>
                <proxyDataProvider ref="proxyDataProviders/main" param1="$(id)"/>
                <archives hint="raw:AddArchive">
                    <archive name="archive"/>
                    <archive name="recyclebin"/>
                </archives>
                <cacheSizes hint="setting">
                    <data>20MB</data>
                    <items>10MB</items>
                    <paths>500KB</paths>
                    <itempaths>10MB</itempaths>
                    <standardValues>500KB</standardValues>
                </cacheSizes>
            </database>
        </databases>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

If we pull up the admin page that shows the final config, https://example.com/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx we have the following, where we can see that `sc.include` elements aren't being replaced as they are with the other sites.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sitecore xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" database="SqlServer">
    <databases>
        <!-- web -->
        <database id="web" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.Database, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <icon>Images/database_web.png</icon>
            <securityEnabled>true</securityEnabled>
            <dataProviders hint="list:AddDataProvider">
                <dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">
                    <disableGroup>publishing</disableGroup>
                    <prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
                        <childLimit>100</childLimit>
                        <logStats>false</logStats>
                        <template desc="template">{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}</template>
                        <template desc="template section">{E269FBB5-3750-427A-9149-7AA950B49301}</template>
                        <template desc="template field">{455A3E98-A627-4B40-8035-E683A0331AC7}</template>
                        <template desc="node">{239F9CF4-E5A0-44E0-B342-0F32CD4C6D8B}</template>
                        <template desc="folder">{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523}</template>
                        <template desc="language">{F68F13A6-3395-426A-B9A1-FA2DC60D94EB}</template>
                        <template desc="device">{B6F7EEB4-E8D7-476F-8936-5ACE6A76F20B}</template>
                        <item desc="root">{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}</item>
                        <children desc="main sections">{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}</children>
                        <!--
    scdev: 10MB
    scstage: 10MB
    scedit: 75MB
    scprod: 150MB
    -->
                        <cacheSize>50MB</cacheSize>
                        <template desc="alias">{54BCFFB7-8F46-4948-AE74-DA5B6B5AFA86}</template>
                        <template desc="layout">{3A45A723-64EE-4919-9D41-02FD40FD1466}</template>
                        <template desc="xsl rendering">{F1F1D639-4F54-40C2-8BE0-81266B392CEB}</template>
                        <item desc="home">{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}</item>
                        <children desc="main items">{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}</children>
                    </prefetch>
                </dataProvider>
            </dataProviders>
            <proxiesEnabled>false</proxiesEnabled>
            <proxyDataProvider ref="proxyDataProviders/main" param1="$(id)" />
            <archives hint="raw:AddArchive">
                <archive name="archive" />
                <archive name="recyclebin" />
            </archives>
            <cacheSizes hint="setting">
                <data>100MB</data>
                <items>50MB</items>
                <paths>2500KB</paths>
                <itempaths>50MB</itempaths>
                <standardValues>2500KB</standardValues>
            </cacheSizes>
            <Engines.DataEngine.Commands.AddFromTemplatePrototype patch:source="Sitecore.Buckets.config">
                <obj type="Sitecore.Buckets.Commands.AddFromTemplateCommand, Sitecore.Buckets" />
            </Engines.DataEngine.Commands.AddFromTemplatePrototype>
        </database>
        <!-- Edit will need to be able to point to both the edit and production databases. -->
        <database id="prodweb" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.Database, Sitecore.Kernel" patch:source="Wsb.Sites.config">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <icon>Network/16x16/earth.png</icon>
            <securityEnabled>true</securityEnabled>
            <dataProviders hint="list:AddDataProvider">
                <dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">
                    <disableGroup>publishing</disableGroup>
                    <prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
                        <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config" />
                        <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Webdb.config" />
                    </prefetch>
                </dataProvider>
            </dataProviders>
            <proxiesEnabled>false</proxiesEnabled>
            <proxyDataProvider ref="proxyDataProviders/main" param1="$(id)" />
            <archives hint="raw:AddArchive">
                <archive name="archive" />
                <archive name="recyclebin" />
            </archives>
            <cacheSizes hint="setting">
                <data>20MB</data>
                <items>10MB</items>
                <paths>500KB</paths>
                <itempaths>10MB</itempaths>
                <standardValues>500KB</standardValues>
            </cacheSizes>
        </database>
    </databases>
</sitecore>
```

I can't find any documentation about this, so while things appear to be working properly, I'm unclear whether it's okay that the `sc.include` elements are not being expanded in this view for the site being patched in.

Should I update the patch file to manually include the items from the two config files (**/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config** and **/App_Config/Prefetch/Webdb.config**) or will Sitecore still do the necessary replacements?

Or is there a better way to add a new `site` via Sitecore patch files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a bug, public reference number 91385.

## Problem

`<sc.include>` cannot be expanded, when it is used in a config file under the Include folder

## Workaround

Manually include items from the referenced configs (or move your configuration to sitecore.config)